# Drush no longer works after Yosemite upgrade

Tags: osx-yosemite, drush

On Mavericks, upgraded to Acquia DD2 (R Feb 10) and Drupal 7.34 for all sites - everything worked fine including Drush.  Then upgraded to Yosemite. Everything works fine except Drush.  Error I get is:

dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
Expected in: /Applications/acquia-drupal/common/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
/Applications/acquia-drupal/drush/drush: line 5: 9812 Trace/BPT trap: 5 "/Applications/acquia-drupal/drush/drush.1" "$@"

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and re install drush or upgrade it. Also what version of drush do you have?